# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Blender's [third moderator election](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Robert Gützkow]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Following additional moderator need, we called on the runner-up of the election and have a new moderator, please welcome:
[image: Timaroberts]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6003950059782144/0).

Comment: Hey Robert, congratulations on winning, and welcome aboard

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos In Stack Exchange tradition I'm not going to reply with a "Thank you", but I very much appreciate the warm welcome!

Comment: Congratulations! Well qualified, for this job.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I agree with them. ;-) Congratulations.

Comment: Very cool :). Congrats.